# Ajuda em condicional no WHERE do SQL

Tags: sql-server, query, if, where, case

Fala pessoal, estou montando uma consulta no SQL.
Nessa consulta, o campo SD1010.D1_TES pode assumir N valores, porém, caso esse campo seja igual a vazio, preciso que mais uma restrição seja aplicada (SF4010.F4_TEXTO NOT LIKE '%*%'). Para isso, primeiro testei utilizar condicionais com CASE e também com if, segue exemplo abaixo:

```
WHERE
.
.
. AND
(
CASE
    WHEN SD1010.D1_TES = '   ' THEN (SF4010.F4_TEXTO NOT LIKE '%*%')
)
```

Acontece que o SQL aponta erro, já tentei colocar parênteses, tirar parênteses, utilizar if else e mesmo assim o erro acontece.

O único jeito que consegui foi duplicando as restrições utilizando o OR e só adicionando a restrição da D1_TES e da F4_TEXTO:

```
WHERE
(
**SD1010.D1_TES = '   ' AND**
-- RETIRA DELETADOS
(SD1010.D_E_L_E_T_<>'*') AND 
(   
    --CLASSIFICADO E ATUALIZOU ESTOQUE
    SF4010.F4_ESTOQUE = 'S' OR
    --PENDENTE DE CLASSIFICACAO PARA ESTOQUE
    (SD1010.D1_CC='' AND SD1010.D1_TES='') 
) AND
SF1010.F1_DTDIGIT>=concat(YEAR(GETDATE()),'0',month(GETDATE())-1,'01') AND -- DADOS INSERIDOS A PARTIR DO PRIMEIRO DIA DO MÊS ANTERIOR
SF1010.F1_DTDIGIT<=GETDATE() AND -- DADOS INSERIDOS ATÉ O DIA DE HOJE
(SF4010.F4_TEXTO NOT LIKE '%*%') AND -- retira importação 1
(SF1010.F1_ESPECIE <> 'SPE  ' OR SF1010.F1_ESPECIE <> 'SPE') AND -- retira importação 2 
(SF1010.F1_ESPECIE NOT LIKE 'NFE') AND  -- retira importação 3 
(SD1010.D1_FILIAL = '09')-- FILTRA FILIAL
) OR
(
-- RETIRA DELETADOS
(SD1010.D_E_L_E_T_<>'*') AND 
(   
    --CLASSIFICADO E ATUALIZOU ESTOQUE
    SF4010.F4_ESTOQUE = 'S' OR
    --PENDENTE DE CLASSIFICACAO PARA ESTOQUE
    (SD1010.D1_CC='' AND SD1010.D1_TES='') 
) AND
SF1010.F1_DTDIGIT>=concat(YEAR(GETDATE()),'0',month(GETDATE())-1,'01') AND -- DADOS INSERIDOS A PARTIR DO PRIMEIRO DIA DO MÊS ANTERIOR
SF1010.F1_DTDIGIT<=GETDATE() AND -- DADOS INSERIDOS ATÉ O DIA DE HOJE
(SF1010.F1_ESPECIE <> 'SPE  ' OR SF1010.F1_ESPECIE <> 'SPE') AND -- retira importação 2 
(SF1010.F1_ESPECIE NOT LIKE 'NFE') AND  -- retira importação 3 
(SD1010.D1_FILIAL = '09')-- FILTRA FILIAL
)
```

Alguem sabe alguma forma que eu possa realizar uma condicional para a restrição ou enxugar esse código e não ter q repetir essas restrições?

Comment: está utilizando `sql-server` certo? adicione essa tag para facilitar o entendimento

Comment: Qual o objetivo deste filtro:  `(SF1010.F1_ESPECIE <> 'SPE  ' OR SF1010.F1_ESPECIE <> 'SPE')`?   Me parece que ele sempre retorna "verdadeiro".

Comment: Atente que as datas aqui são CHAR no formato YYYYMMDD (Protheus Totvs)

Comment: As pessoas se propõe a tentar ajudar e o demandante some.

Answer (score -1):

> *o campo SD1010.D1_TES pode assumir N valores, porém, caso esse campo seja igual a vazio, preciso que mais uma restrição seja aplicada (SF4010.F4_TEXTO NOT LIKE '%*%')*

Verifique se o seguinte filtro atende ao que necessita:

```
-- código #1
...
    and (SD1010.D1_TES <> '   '  or  (SD1010.D1_TES = '   ' and SF4010.F4_TEXTO NOT LIKE '%*%'))
...
```

---

Outra sugestão:

```
-- código #2
...
and 1 = (case when SD1010.D1_TES = '   ' 
                   then case when SF4010.F4_TEXTO NOT LIKE '%*%' then 1 
                             else 0 end
              else 1 end)
...
```

---

Os predicados presentes na cláusula WHERE precisam de uma revisão completa.

**(1)**

```
SF1010.F1_DTDIGIT>=concat(YEAR(GETDATE()),'0',month(GETDATE())-1,'01')
```

Se o mês corrente for novembro, dezembro ou janeiro, o trecho `concat(YEAR(GETDATE()),'0',month(GETDATE())-1,'01')` retorna valor incorreto. Por exemplo, se a data do dia de execução for 25/12/2019, o valor retornado por essa expressão é '201901101'.

Sugiro que substitua por

```
SF1010.F1_DTDIGIT >= convert (char(8), dateadd (month, (dateadd (month, 0, current_timestamp) -1), 0), 112) and
```

Para entender a expressão proposta, execute o seguinte código

```
-- código #3 v2
SELECT dateadd (month, 0, current_timestamp) as P1,  -- número de meses desde "o início dos tempos"
       (dateadd (month, 0, current_timestamp) -1) as P2,
       dateadd (month, (dateadd (month, 0, current_timestamp) -1), 0) as P3,
       convert (char(8), dateadd (month, (dateadd (month, 0, current_timestamp) -1), 0), 112) as P4;
```

**(2)**

```
SF1010.F1_DTDIGIT<=GETDATE() AND -- DADOS INSERIDOS ATÉ O DIA DE HOJE
```

Se é até o dia de hoje, então não é necessário testar.

**(3)**

Sobre `SF1010.F1_ESPECIE NOT LIKE 'NFE'`, melhor usar `SF1010.F1_ESPECIE <> 'NFE'`

Answer (score -1):

Tentou utilizar o filtro dessa forma?

> AND (SD1010.D1_TES <> '   ' OR SF4010.F4_TEXTO NOT LIKE '%*%')